# OnPropertyChanged not firing on nested class' property

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have some issues with OnPropertyChanged.

On my View, I wrote:

```
<StackPanel>
     <Label Content="{Binding TestProperty, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
     <Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

This Data Context is:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string TestProperty
    {
        get
        {
            if (TestWrapperModel.Instance.TestModel == null)
                return "Test Initial String";
            return TestWrapperModel.Instance.TestModel.TestProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

My TestWrapperModel is just a simple singleton wrapper that implements PropertyChangedBase.

My TestModel is like:

```
class TestModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private String _testProperty= "";

    public String TestProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _testProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _testProperty= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TestProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

PropertyChangedBase is an abstract class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Whenever I change the value of TestProperty, OnPropertyChanged fires, but the label on the UI doesn't show the new value (So it always display "Test Initial String"). Snoop says the  binding works.

I think it's a simple problem and I just can't see what the problem is. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try to put the OnPropertyChanged into the property setter of the viewmodel - i guess you are binding to that one, not? Though there is no such setter, handle the property changed event of the model and pass it through the viewmodel.

Comment: This is the third time this question has come up with slightly different edit and comments gone.  And no edit history.  Are you deleting and re-posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work, since you `DataContext` is your `MainWindowViewModel` class, and not your `TestModel` class. When the application starts, it gets the value from `TestProperty` only once, and if doesn't change it won't change the label's value.

You should write the `set` on your `TestProperty` on the `MainWindowViewModel` to change your label.

Answer (score 1):

You need to propagate the event from the child viewmodel to the parent viewModel.

Subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of `TestModel` and raise a further `PropertyChanged` event in your `MainWindowViewModel` class to notify the view that the `TestProperty` property has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `PropertyChanged` event fires *on the model*, but you are binding *on the viewmodel*. If the latter doesn't invoke its own `PropertyChanged` event the binding engine doesn't know that things have changed.